# SQL Update Query - Attempt to put 0 in a field

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server

I'm using the following to update a row in a SQL Server database:

```
"UPDATE bmraconfig
    SET
    [PN Operator] = '".$PNOp."',
    [PN Value] = '".$PNValue."',
    [MEL Operator] = '".$MELOp."',
    [MEL Value] = '".$MELValue."',
    [NDZ Operator] = '".$NDZOp."',
    [NDZ Value] = '".$NDZValue."',
    [Fuel Type] = '".htmlentities($FuelType, ENT_QUOTES)."'

    WHERE
    [PN Operator] = '".$default["PNOp"]."'
    ";
```

However when one of the variables is equal to `0`, for example `$MELValue == 0,` that field isn't updated. If the value was `51` for example it will change, but not when it's a `0`.

Comment: It is because your trying to put a string in a column likely designated for a number. Are you checking for or getting any errors?

Comment: @JayBlanchard No errors are output when I submit the query

Comment: This seems very unlikely. The only way this would be the case is if there's some sort of rules/constraints on the columns in the sql table themselves.

Can you paste the surrounding code? may give more of a picture.

Comment: Check your error logs.

Comment: Beware of little booby tables.

Comment: @Manachi
The data type of the fields are nvarchar(3) if that helps?

Comment: Is there a trigger on the table?